# Cordova App - unfortunately [app name] has stopped

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I have a Cordova app that was working properly on both ripple emulator and Android devices. For some odd reason, the app decided not to work on Android devices while it still run fine on ripple emulator. Whenever I try to deploy the app on any Android device, I get "unfortunately [app name] has stopped" alert on my device.

After few days of research, I am still unable to determine the cause of this issue although I am suspecting that it may be related to plugins. I tried to remove some unnecessary plugins but still I am unable to run on Android devices.

Any advice or direction is appreciated.

Config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:vs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/htmlapps" id="com.b8ak.b8akapp" version="1.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" defaultlocale="en-US">
  <name>B8ak بيتك</name>
  <description>A blank project that uses Apache Cordova to help you build an app that targets multiple mobile platforms: Android, iOS, Windows, and Windows Phone.</description>
  <author href="http://cordova.io" email="dev@cordova.apache.org">Eyad Alshabaan</author>
  <content src="index.html" />
  <access origin="*" />
  <!--To Grand Access to some href tags SEE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26271313/tel-sms-and-mailto-no-longer-working-in-android-after-upgrading-to-cordo-->
  <!--<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes"/>
  <access origin="geo:*" launch-external="yes"/>
  <access origin="mailto:*" launch-external="yes"/>
  <access origin="sms:*" launch-external="yes"/>
  <access origin="market:*" launch-external="yes"/>-->
  <vs:features />
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
  <preference name="windows-target-version" value="8.1" />
  <preference name="windows-phone-target-version" value="8.1" />
  <platform name="android">
    <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <!-- iOS 8.0+ -->
    <!-- iPhone 6 Plus  -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-3x.png" width="180" height="180" />
    <!-- iOS 7.0+ -->
    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-2x.png" width="120" height="120" />
    <!-- iPad -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-76-2x.png" width="152" height="152" />
    <!-- iOS 6.1 -->
    <!-- Spotlight Icon -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-40-2x.png" width="80" height="80" />
    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" height="114" />
    <!-- iPad -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" height="144" />
    <!-- iPhone Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-small-2x.png" width="58" height="58" />
    <!-- iPad Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-50-2x.png" width="100" height="100" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="windows">
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="150" height="150" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="360" height="360" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png" width="30" height="30" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png" width="" height="" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png" width="106" height="106" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png" width="70" height="70" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png" width="170" height="170" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/StoreLogo.scale-100.png" width="50" height="50" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/StoreLogo.scale-240.png" width="120" height="120" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" height="150" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="744" height="360" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="wp8">
    <icon src="res/icons/wp8/ApplicationIcon.png" width="62" height="62" />
    <icon src="res/icons/wp8/Background.png" width="173" height="173" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="android">
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png" density="land-hdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png" density="land-ldpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png" density="land-mdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png" density="land-xhdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" density="port-hdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" density="port-ldpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" density="port-mdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" density="port-xhdpi" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" height="480" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" height="960" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" height="1024" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png" width="1536" height="2048" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" height="768" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png" width="2048" height="1536" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-568h-2x.png" width="640" height="1136" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-667h.png" width="750" height="1334" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-736h.png" width="2208" height="1242" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="windows">
    <splash src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreen.scale-100.png" width="620" height="300" />
    <splash src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreen.scale-240.png" width="1152" height="1920" />
    <splash src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreenPhone.scale-240.png" width="1152" height="1920" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="wp8">
    <splash src="res/screens/wp8/SplashScreenImage.jpg" width="480" height="800" />
  </platform>
  <vs:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" version="0.3.12" />
  <vs:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" version="0.2.15" />
  <vs:plugin name="com.microsoft.azure-mobile-services" version="1.2.8" />
  <preference name="KeepRunning" value="True" />
  <preference name="ShowTitle" value="False" />
  <preference name="InAppBrowserStorageEnabled" value="True" />
  <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="False" />
  <preference name="Fullscreen" value="False" />
  <vs:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" version="0.3.0" />
  <vs:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.statusbar" version="0.1.10" />
  <preference name="target-device" value="handset" />
  <vs:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" version="0.6.0" />
</widget>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10001" android:versionName="1.0.1" package="com.b8ak.b8akapp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="msopentech.azure.NotificationHub$PushNotificationReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="io.cordova.myapp67592dd97b174b21bbc07f89808a88f9" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.TriggerReceiver" />
        <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.ClearReceiver" />
        <activity android:exported="false" android:launchMode="singleInstance" android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.ClickActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" />
        <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.notification.TriggerReceiver" />
        <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.notification.ClearReceiver" />
        <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.RestoreReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity android:exported="false" android:launchMode="singleInstance" android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.notification.ClickActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" />
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <permission android:name="io.cordova.myapp67592dd97b174b21bbc07f89808a88f9.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="io.cordova.myapp67592dd97b174b21bbc07f89808a88f9.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I debugged the app by connecting my device while running Android Studio and analyzing the logcat output. I noticed that the plugin StatusBar was throwing an error. I removed it and added it again in my project and now everything works fine :)

Comment: I had the same problem with cordova-sqlite-storage. Same solution: remove the plugin, add it again, and rebuild.

Answer (score 9):

I know this is an old thread, but I'll share how I diagnosed my app.

Using windows cmd: `adb logcat | findstr /R /C:"com.company.application"`

This will make sure that logcat is listening to your app.
Then I ctrl+c right after the Error pops up. I selected all the log output from the console and pasted in notepad then looked for the keyword "FATAL" most likely it's the culprit.